# Magnitude of convexity

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, hessian-matrix

I came across such concept:
 If integral over second derivative of function $g : R \rightarrow R$ : $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} [g''(x)]^2dx$ is high, then function is more "wiggly", and the lower value of this integral the more smooth is function.
How to apply this concept to multivariable function $f : R^{n} \rightarrow R$? Calculate the integral over matrix norm of hessian matrix of this function?

Could you suggest either heuristical or strictly theoretical approach to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably want the absolute value of the second derivative in that integral, otherwise the fundamental theorem of calculus tells you it just depends on the limit of the derivative at the endpoints (so no actual local information).

Comment: yes sorry for mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, integrating $g''(x)$ doesn't work well as a measure since you can have cancellation if there are places where $g$ is convex and other places where $g$ is concave.  Rather, you'd typically regularize by minimizing

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g''(x)^{2} dx$

In higher dimensions, the Laplacian of $g$ is typically used:

$\int_{R^{n}} (\Delta g(x))^{2} dx $

Here

$\Delta g(x)= \frac{\partial^{2} g(x)}{\partial x_{1}^{2}} + \cdots + \frac{\partial^{2} g(x)}{\partial x_{n}^{2}}$.